# Pass data read from a database to a javascript function privately

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using the amCharts javascript library to show some data charts in my website. I want to read the data that will be in the charts from a database.

I'm reading the data with and after that making a call to the javascript function like this:

```
<?php
    echo '<script language="javascript">makeGraph(' . json_encode($data) . ')</script>';
?>
```

I am getting the results I want this way, but if a client look in the source code of the website, he will see all the data from the database instead of $data since you are not in the server anymore.

So the question is: how can I read and use all the data without exposing it publicly? Because I can not really figure out any other way to do it now.

Thank you very much

Comment: try using node.js. any client-side javascript will be readable because thats how javascript is by nature.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want users to see your data, then don't use JavaScript to process it.  Create the charts in php on your server and display the results only.

Comment: Is there any way to create the chart in PHP using a Javascript library like amCharts or HighCharts? If not, any recommendation of something like these libraries but in PHP?

Comment: No because the Javascript is run in the browser and PHP is run on the server.  So you will have to find one, I have not used these libraries presonally so I cannot make any recommendations.  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+charts